# Evaluate integral using R

Tags: r, simulation, monte-carlo

I need to evaluate $\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{1}\int_{1}^{1}\int_{1}^{1}(y)e^{x+}}dxdz}$ using in R.

Here is my attempt:

```
f <- function(A) {
  x <- A[1]
  y <- A[2]
  z <- A[3]
  return (exp(x+y+(z^2)))
}

N <- 10000000
sum <- 0
set.seed(5)
X <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 2)
Y <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 2)
Z <- runif(N, min = 0, max = 2)
for(i in 1:N){
  k <- f(c(X[i], Y[i], Z[i]))
  sum <- sum + k
}
Value <- (sum * 8) / N
print(Value)
```

The f function is defined at the beginning of the code. It takes a vector A of length 3 as input, and returns the value of the function at the point $(x,y,z) = (A[1], A[2], A[3])$.

The runif function is used to generate $N$ random numbers from a uniform distribution between 0 and 2. These numbers are used to sample points in the region of integration. The for loop then iterates over the random points, evaluating the function at each point and adding the result to a running sum.

Finally, the average function value is calculated by dividing the sum by $N$ and multiplying by the volume of the region of integration, which is 8 in this case (since the region is a unit cube with sides of length 2).

However, I'm getting 671.5147 and it's far from . (based on Wolfram Alpha).

Anything wrong with the code? Which part is wrong or can be improved?

Comment: Aren't you missing `x+y` in the function $f$ ?

Comment: You edited the code in response to the answer but you did not accept the answer. Is there still an error? If I compute your code then I get a correct outcome around 1763.7

Comment: @Xi'an Agreed, so I rolled the post back to its original version.

Answer (score 5):

There is a mistake in the R code, `(x+y)` is missing in front of the exponential within function `f`: when adding this sum,

```
f <- function(A, B = sum(A[-3])) {
  return(B*exp(B+A[3]^2))
}

print( 8*sum(apply(X = 2*matrix(runif(3e7), ncol=3), 
                   MARGIN = 1, 
                   FUN = f))/1e7)
```

correctly returns

```
[1] 1763.745
```

Comment: Hey Christian, this answer (+1) is being flagged as low-quality :-O

Comment: I am really intrigued by the recent behavior of low quality queue. Of late, many legit answers have been stacked in the queue.